# Bulk Update - BulkWriteResult.nMatched and BulkWriteResult.nModified returning 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Main server.js code where i start my server and connects to mongoDb Server

```
if(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI) {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
} else {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/itrack");
}

global.db = mongoose;

mongoose.connection.on('open', function() {
    // This line is getting printed here
    console.log('Mongoose opened.');
});
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
    console.log('Worker ' + process.pid + ' is alive!');
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port:', app.get('port'));
    });
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
    process.exit(0);
}); 

// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected'); 
});
```

Now inside my controller/customer/router.js Controller file,

```
router.put("/addstud/:route", function(req,res,next) {

var custId = req.user.id;
var studList = req.body;
var route = req.params.route;

db.connection.on('open', function() {
    // Never goes inside this As i have to bulk Update Operation
    console.log('Mongoose opened.');
});

db.connection.once('open',function(err,conn) {
    // Nor this 
}

});

var bulk = Student.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

// this simple code is not working
bulk.find({_id:'56f940172681fda5c6536a4d'})
 .updateOne( {name:'test'});

bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("ERROR WHILE INSERTING "+err);
    } else {
    // This line is getting printed means no error but nothing changed in DB
        console.log("RESULT "+result.mMatched); // 0 ! HOW ????????
    }
});
```

But inside the same class i can easily retrieved and add data to Db using Mongoose Model.

Comment: how are you passing `mongoose` instance in router.js ?

Comment: about that, i am requiring a new instance.
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); This is what i have done to generate new schema for all my models

Comment: you should have one global connection to mongodb in startup file and then pass it to required routes .

Comment: Okay you mean by module.exports, how then is it working for all my models, like when i use Model.query its works perfectly

Comment: Depends on your architecture sire. If you are calling your routes via main server file you don't need to export anything. Just use mongoose when you are creating schema.

Comment: @MukeshSharma  Even after using a single global DB connection, still the same problem, I have updated the code in the question

Comment: I think that the `db.connection.on('open',...` in router.js is not called because the db is already connected before you require router.js.

Comment: That last is what you are missing here. The "event" only fires "once" or in the case of "open" then still "once" every time the database connection is initially established. The "intent" is to put **all** of your code inside such a call. For instance, around the startup of the http listener, so that the application is not running in that sense "until" the database connection is actually made. So you don't actually **need** the other calls, since the database is already connected before that code can actually be executed. By design.

Comment: How can i ensure that my connection is established, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783575/mongoose-bulk-update-operation
My simple bulk update code is not working i have given everything correctly,
Thats when i have started adding connection.on('open' ) events listener

Comment: It worked with other key, I guess its because i have not add ObjectId("56f940172681fda5c6536a4d") , thank you all !

How do i mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the id in object. Using it like a string will not work. Do like this:

```
const restful = require('node-restful');
const mongoose = restful.mongoose;

let id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('56f940172681fda5c6536a4d');
let obj = {"_id": id};

// And then

bulk.find({_id:'56f940172681fda5c6536a4d'}).updateOne( {name:'test'});
```